# Firebase Database for Android, return Map data as a String

Tags: java, android, database, firebase

So for my project, I'm sending a Server Timestamp to Firebase then immediately retrieving it to convert to a String, to use as a unique identifier for user-created objects.

The data is nested under `Timestamps/UserID/[this is where the timestamp is]`

The problem is that when retrieving the data you can't add a map object as a child() on an `addValueEventListener` so I'm stuck with retrieving the user's Unique ID instead of the timestamp.

This returns something along the lines of:

```
DataSnapshot{key = [User's Unique ID], value = [timestamp i'm trying to isolate]}
```

Instead of retrieving all the gibberish, I just want the timestamp.

Here's the code, thanks in advance.

```
    public void createFlat(){

    /////WRITE TIMESTAMP VALUE TO SERVER UNDER TEMP NODE/////
    final Map timestampMap = ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;


    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Timestamps")
            .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
            .setValue(timestampMap)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"timestamp written",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        /////RETRIEVE TIMESTAMP FROM SERVER AND CONVERT IT TO A STRING/////
                        final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                        String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

                        DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("Timestamps").child(uid); //here is the issue, can't add child(timestampMap)

                                ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                        String timestampString = dataSnapshot.toString();
                                        textView2.setText(timestampString);
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                });

                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),task.getException().getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`DataSnapshot` object contains both *Key* and *Value*. First you must get the value and only then you can call `toString()`. This below line would do...

```
String timestampString = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't call `toString()` directly on the snapshot.  Call it on the value contained within the snapshot, using [getValue()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot.html#getValue()):

```
String timestampString = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
```